# Jackrabbit file storage

Tags: jackrabbit

I want to test saving and retrieving of files using Apache Jackrabbit.  I am not sure if it's saving when I am not able to retrieve it later.  The following is my code.  My question is how do I retrieve the file that I have saved.

```java
    @Test
    public void storeFile() throws Exception {
        File file = getFile();
        FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file);
         
        Repository repository = new TransientRepository(); 
        Session session = repository.login( 
        new SimpleCredentials("username", "password".toCharArray())); 
        try { 
            logger.info("logged in as user '{}'", session.getUserID());
            Node root = session.getRootNode(); 

            // Store content 
            Node hello = root.addNode("userid_12"); 
            Node world = hello.addNode("files"); 
            
            
            logger.debug("setting fileInputStream");
            world.getSession().getValueFactory().createBinary(fileInputStream);
            
            session.save(); 

            // Retrieve content 
            Node node = root.getNode("userid_12/files"); 
            logger.info(node.getPath()); 
            //how do I retrieve the file now?
          }
```

Answer (score 4):

Just recently done something similar, and used the examples page (http://wiki.apache.org/jackrabbit/ExamplesPage) to do it.

You need to tell jackrabbit the node type and also pass it the binary data and the mime type when saving, something like this:

```
Node DocNode = currentDocNode.addNode(doc.getFilename(),"nt:file");
    Node contentNode = DocNode.addNode("jcr:content","nt:resource");
    Binary binary = session.getValueFactory().createBinary(file.getInputStream());
    contentNode.setProperty("jcr:data",binary);
    contentNode.setProperty("jcr:mimeType",file.getContentType());
    Calendar created = Calendar.getInstance ();
    contentNode.setProperty("jcr:lastModified", created);
```

This will save the document correctly in the node. Then retrieving the file is just getting the node and reading the data, there is a JcrUtils class that does this for you:

```
Node fileNode = root.getNode("path/to/node");
InputStream stream = null;
if(null != fileNode){
 stream = JcrUtils.readFile(fileNode);
}
```

Then you can do what you what with the inputStream (stream it to response etc)